# Is it possible to block ExitWindows or ExitWindowsEx?

Tags: winapi

I'm using a corporate workstation, and my IT department keeps using programs to restart my PC without my permission. I've asked them to stop, but they don't how how - typical.

Anyway, I figured there must be a way of preventing (malicious?) programs like these from restarting my PC... So how about preventing `ExitWindows` or `ExitWindowsEx` from being called? I assume this is what they'll be using, but I'm not sure how to find out.

Is this a good solution, or should I just move to another company?

#### Update 1:

Just thinking about this from another angle - is it possible to tell which program is making a call to `ExitWindows` or `ExitWindowsEx`? This way I can log the process name, and then write a small program to blacklist the offending program (i.e. kill it whenever it appears).

Comment: If they force the restart, then theres pretty much nothing you can do.  
What if you leave an unsaved notepad document open and when they call the restart it asks if you want "save the changes" and then you press cancel?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why the vote to close? Maybe a sysadmin is lurking.

Comment: @Imre L: Yeah I've tried this sort of thing, when I come to my machine in the morning, all my work is lost -- no prompts.

Comment: Ask this at severfault.com, home of the sys admins.

Comment: This is extremely common behaviour by IT departments - usually to install essential updates and security patches.  Can you ask them to provide notice of when this is happening?  If it's out of hours (per comment below) then you don't have much of a case to ask them to stop, but giving you some notice that this will happen is only common courtesy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On < Vista, you can handle [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(VS.85).aspx), on Vista+, you need to use [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877(v=VS.85).aspx) in addition to WM_QUERYENDSESSION.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop it by running `shutdown /a` on the command-line once you see the System Shutdown dialog.

Comment: They often schedule the restart in the middle of the night when I'm away from my desk. I have tried using `shutdown /a` when their fruity little count-down dialogue appears, but it seems that they're not using the shutdown command to schedule shutdowns. I think the actual application it's self (anti virus maybe?) is making a call to shutdown via the winapi.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the appropriate rights, use `shutdown -a` to abort a scheduled shutdown; alternatively, write a small program that catches [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890%28VS.85%29.aspx) and answers with zero.

But I think the real problem here is your IT department interrupting your work. Talk with your manager before you take any other action, and make sure she understands that this is impacting your performance.