# Blocking a log off request with Python

Tags: python, windows, logoff

I have some software that occasionally logs me off automaticly. I want to block this, so I won't be logged off (windows 7). Are there a way to block log off requests using Python? If so, then how and if not; are there any other solutions?

Comment: Simplest solution would seem to be to remove the software that's causing you to log off.

Comment: The software is needed

Comment: Not sure why Python specifically? You would need a program running that would cause receive the shutdown/logoff message, but blocking it is a bad thing to do - it must be logging you off for a reason.

Comment: @SimonLarsen What exactly is this software which is causing the logouts?

Comment: It doesn't have to be Python; I only said that because I'm familiar with the language. The software is called softXpand and I don't see why that is relevant?

Comment: @SimonLarsen it is relevant because people are trying to help you and can better help if they know what software is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks as if there's a possible solution in an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376876%28VS.85%29.aspx).

What you'd have to do is write a simple Windows application which handles the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` event, and returns `FALSE`, then, in theory, as long as that application is running, the system won't log you out. It's possible that just leaving open an instance of `notepad.exe` with an unsaved file in it would achieve the same thing.

It, might, however, cause all other applications to terminate, so, if that's undesirable, you'd have to intercept the call to `ExitWindows` from softXpand, which is much more complicated.

Some security products like [Comodo Internet Security](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php) will allow you to run an application in a sandbox, such that you can intercept and deny certain system calls, which might work.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625519/is-it-possible-to-block-exitwindows-or-exitwindowsex).